# Best way to go about sharing iPhone app revenue with client(s)?

Tags: iphone, app-store, sharing, revenue

Finally got my first iPhone app ready for launch.

- There's a large publisher backing the IP.
- There's a third party between me (developer) and the publisher.

Everybody wants a cut.

What are some ways of going about this? There's probably enough of you who have expierences, do's, don't and tips?

I was thinking of just putting it all on my account and have them invoice me for the various amounts every 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they agree to it then you idea is the best because it keeps you in control of the process, although you might have to consider tax issues. For example, depending on where you live you might get charged tax on 100% of the revenue rather than just your cut.

No matter what you do though, make sure you have a legal agreement between you and all of the parties involved regarding the the revenue split. This way everyone is on the same page and you can be reasonably assured that someone won't change their mind once the money rolls in.

Comment: Good thinking, we have the agreement down in basics, but the details of the who-pays-when is not documenten. I'll have their legaldepartment draft something.